# Laravel dusk test fails on CI (github actions) but succeeds locally

Tags: github-actions, laravel-dusk

One of our tests fails on CI, while running the test locally results in the test passing. I've been trying to figure out why for hours/days now, and I still can't seem to fix it.

**The test**

The steps of the test are as follows:

1. Register as a new user
2. Confirm the sent email in order to login by clicking a link
3. Once logged in, click a link in the dashboard and check if you're on the page.

```
// $signup & $address are dusk pages
$browser->visit($signup)
    ->acceptCookies()
    ->signup([
        'firstName' => 'John',
        'email' => 'john.doe@example.org',
        'password' => 'john.doe',
    ])
    ->on($thanks)
    ->visitMail($confirmationMail)
    ->withinMail(fn (DuskBrowser $browser) => $browser->click('@confirmLink'))
    ->switchToLatestWindow()
    ->on($dashboard)
    ->click('@editAddressButton')
    ->on($address)
```

Every step succeeds until the last line. When the browser asserts it's on the "address" page, the assertion fails. The assertion is based on seeing certain text displayed.
This makes sense, because when dumping the page (on CI) after clicking `@editAddressButton`, the page is empty like so: `<html><body></body></html>`.

All dependencies are up-to-date and the same version, as well for chrome-driver.

**Conclusion**

I'm just baffled why it fails at **that** specific point on CI, but not locally. Our other tests do succeed, so it's not like our .env files are setup incorrectly.

Thank you for your time reading this, I sincerely hope that someone can help us figure this out.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Experiencing basically the exact same problem for a few days now, horrible to debug.

Comment: @HashimAziz not yet... we left it for what it is for some time, coincidentally im currently having another go with this. Might have some progress but I'm not sure..

Comment: I've posted a detailed issue [here](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/975) as a potential bug report but based on their previous reactions to the rest of the issues in that repo I have a feeling the Dusk devs will be closing it as a matter of course. I hope I'm wrong, but it looks like they seem to value having zero open issues more than actually resolving bugs.

Comment: Nice job explaining the issue, let's hope we can solve this issue so we can get our dusk tests running again :). If I have progress from my side, I'll be sure to let you know.

Comment: I actually solved this for myself yesterday, I'll post a solution later on today.

Comment: Awesome! Looking forward to your solution, curious how you managed to fix it

Comment: Here it is, let me know if it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71960113/1191147.